# How do I populate a dropdown from a different model in Razor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I am working on a project where I have one main model that needs to include many other models and display them on the view for the main model. I can't seem to bring over data from them that I need to populate in dropdowns.

One of my smaller models is Entity and looks like this:

```
   public class Entity
{
    //[Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Active { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the markup language that I am trying to bring the selectlist items to:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.EntityID" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="SecurityLog.EntityID" class="form-control switch-disable" asp-items="EntityID">
                        <option value="">--Select Entity--</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.EntityID" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

On my EditModel page I created a Entity viewData and can not get the results to appear in the markup. It is called "EntityID":

```
            ViewData["EntityID"] = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a => a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "Name");
```

I can't seem to make the ViewData show anything and have been trying for the better part of the afternoon. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `asp-items="ViewBag.EntityID"`

Comment: I tried ViewData and just the word but didn't even think about that. It works perfect now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close...

The ViewData EntityID property can be accessed on the razor page via *ViewBag*.

**Razor Page**

```
<select id="entity" asp-for="SecurityLog.EntityID" class="form-control" asp- 
        items="ViewBag.EntityID">
    <option value="">--Select Entity--</option>
</select>
```

**OnGetAsync**

```
ViewData["EntityID"] = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a => a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "Name");
```

Comment: It now works perfectly and I will implement this for my other lists.